# Быстрый сериализатор для классов на C++?

Tags: c++, сериализация, десериализация, unreal-engine-5

Какие есть быстрые сериализаторы классов C++ ?

Нужно сериализовать любой класс в строку или байты которые можно записать на диск.Затем из них восстановить объект.

Что важно.
Должна быть поддержка кастомного метода сериализации и десериализации, который можно добавлять в свои классы чтобы управлять тем что должно и как сериализоваться.

Псевдокод:

```
class MyClass
   {

       int a;
       TArray < MyCustomClass > arr;

       Byte[] serialise();
       MyClass deserialise(Byte[]);
   };

   MyClass obj;
   auto serObj = obj.serialise();
   MyClass loaded = MyClass::deserialise(serObj);
```

Comment: Если это вопрос по unreal engine, то там есть встроенный https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UObject/Serialize/2/ Хотя он не быстрый.

Comment: Сами напишите с рекурсией : создаёте примерно такие строки : `{"имя типа",{.. ..},..,{"int","123"}}`

Comment: @user7860670
Там требуется все классы наследовать от UObject и переименовывать их. А меня интересует как раз способ чтобы этого не пришлось делать.

Comment: тогда вам сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+

Comment: @user7860670
Там нет такой информации. Мне нужна библиотека которая бы поддерживала запись в поток данных, с возможностью перегрузки методов в самих классах, чтобы управлять самой сериализацией в каждом классе отдельно. И чтобы это работало максимально быстро. Может кто знает такие библиотеки или классы. например как работать с FArchive из самого unreal. В C# я использовал Ceras, а в C++ не могу найти хороший аналог.

Comment: ¿Чем не устроили библиотеки, перечисленные в ответах по ссылке выше?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html

Comment: https://protobuf.dev/